# Mobile Website Or ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to build a website which would mostly be used / browsed via mobile. When choosing the IDE to develop this, I find out that VS 2005 supports Mobile Web form while in other IDEs (VS 2k8, 2k12, 2k15) I didn't find Mobile Web Form. 
I know the different between the Mob and Normal Web form, However, I didn't understand why Mobile Web form is not available in other IDEs which I mentioned?

If I design in normal web page, will it fit in mobile?

Comment: You don't need really need separate IDE for designing mobile website. Wesites are made responsive using CSS these days. You can use VS12, VS10 or even VS08 to do that. Normal webforms (aspx pages) with Responsive CSS will fit in mobile.

Comment: thanks, I think i have to go and study some CSS, would appreciate to have your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC can be made responsive using CSS media queries. In early days, developer used to create separate pages for mobile and desktop. Now, you don't have to create separate pages with separate css and you can avoid device detection logic and desktop to mobile redirecting.

In simple words, media queries allows you to decide each and every styling property of the HTML components on Desktop, tabs and mobile. Please learn some basic here at [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Moving ahead I would suggest you to use the Bootstrap for asp.net and here's the tutorial to use [ASP.NET Webforms with Bootstrap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815916/Create-an-ASP-NET-Web-Forms-Application-using-Boot)